# C'est, c'était, ce fut dans un discours narratif au passé

Tags: passé-composé, imparfait, passé-simple, narration

Y a-t-il une règle qui permet de décider entre **c'est/c'était/ce fut** dans un discours narratif au passé (dans un langage plutôt soutenu)?

Quelques exemples (j'utilise **c'est** pas défaut, sans préjuger de la bonne forme)

> Elle regarda les gens. "Je dois partir" pensa-t-elle. **C'est** ce qu'elle
> fit.

> L'homme parlait. Le problème, **c'est** qu'elle ne voulait pas écouter.

> Elle le reconnut, **c'est** bien l'homme qu'elle avait vu la veille.

> Tout à coup, le fil céda. **C'est** ainsi que tout se résolut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

- Elle regarda les gens. "Je dois partir" pensa-t-elle. C'est ce qu'elle fit.

Le verbe d'état, « être »,  ne porte pas sur un état relatif au contexte. Si on considère les phrases « Elle regarda les gens. "Je dois partir" pensa-t-elle. C'était ce qu'elle avait à faire. », on voit que l'imparfait convient pour ce contexte. Cependant, il ne convient pas pour la phrase initiale.

- <s>Elle regarda les gens. "Je dois partir" pensa-t-elle. C'était ce qu'elle fit.</s> (*« C'était mais ça ne le serait plus », ce qui n'est pas juste.*)

L'état d'être vrai de l'action donnée (puisque elle a été faite), serait valide jusqu'à un certain temps dans le passé, mais après cela elle pourrait ne pas être considérée comme faite, ce qui est du non-sens ; le présent est ici un présent de vérité générale (faits et états qui ne peuvent pas être contredits, ([valeurs du présent](https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/cours/valeurs-du-present.html)), et ce présent est la seule possibilité.

Dans le cas de « C'était ce qu'elle avait à faire », il ne s'agit plus de « partir » en tant qu'action qui a été réalisée, mais de « partir » en tant que nécessité ; « partir » n'est plus considéré comme une action mais comme une action nécessaire (équivalent : « C'était son besoin ») ; il s'agit donc de la vérité  ou (même chose) de l'affirmation d'un état, qui est celui d'être dans la nécessité de partir ; on peut  considérer cette nécessité sur le plan d'une obligation sujette au contexte du moment ou non ; cette nécessité était dictée par son analyse personnelle ou par d'autres éléments du contexte du moment. On peut aussi utiliser le présent de vérité générale dans ce cas (C'est ce qu'elle avait à faire.) si en tant que commentateur de la situation on considère que la personne qui est forcée de faire quelque chose est sujette à un contexte général qui n'offre pas d'autre alternative. Par exemple, dans le cas du contexte du moment la phrase pourrait être « C'était ce qu'elle avait à faire dans ces conditions mais de nos jours ce serait différent. »

2.

- L'homme parlait. Le problème, c'est qu'elle ne voulait pas écouter.

Le problème n'existe plus, donc l'imparfait est préférable.

- *L'homme parlait. Le problème, c'était qu'elle ne voulait pas écouter.*

Si on nous dit « La voiture ne démarrait pas le mois dernier. » on ne pose pas la question « Quel est le problème ? », parce qu'il est clair qu'il n'y a plus de problème, et on dit plutôt « Quel était le problème ? » (ou, familier, « Qu'est-ce que c'était le problème ? ») ; on répond, par force, « c'était un problème de …. ».

3.

- Elle le reconnut, c'est bien l'homme qu'elle avait vu la veille.

Seul l'imparfait convient parce que le moment où l'identification est faite est dans le passé et c'est à ce moment seulement que la certitude de la validité ( c'était bien) de l'identification est manifestée.

- Elle le reconnut, c'était bien l'homme qu'elle avait vu la veille.

4. 

- Tout à coup, le fil céda. C'est ainsi que tout se résolut.

Dans ce dernier cas on se retrouve au n° 1/. Un moment de réflexion permettra de voir l'analogie. Seulement le présent convient (présent de vérité générale).

---

*Supplément suite à un commentaire de [**user Benoit**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/45514/cest-c%c3%a9tait-ce-fut-dans-un-discours-narratif-au-pass%c3%a9/45519?noredirect=1#comment92765_45519)*

Avant de s'intéresser à cette question supplémentaire examinons un détail qui peut prêter à confusion ; cette digression consolidera l'idée que l'imparfait ne convient pas dans « 1/ ».

[aspects de l'imparfait,    Pascal ROULOIS](https://neuropedagogie.com/conjugaison-francais/imparfait-indicatif.html) (caractères gras dus à user LPH)

> […] lorsqu'il s'agit d'énoncer une vérité générale, on peut utiliser soit le présent, soit l'imparfait.
> ♦ Exemple (au présent) : Le professeur expliqua à ses étudiants que la neuropédagogie **est** une discipline qui intègre des éléments de psychologie cognitive, de pédagogie, de sciences de l'éducation, de psychologie scolaire et comportementale, de neurosciences. [(user LPH) aspect de la vérité générale sans restriction sur le temps (en pratique)]
> ♦ Exemple (à l'imparfait) : Le professeur expliqua à ses étudiants que la neuropédagogie **était** une discipline qui intégrait des éléments de psychologie cognitive, de pédagogie, de sciences de l'éducation, de psychologie scolaire et comportementale, de neurosciences. [(user LPH) aspect de la vérité générale sans restriction sur le temps  (en pratique)]

On est donc porté à croire en une équivalence des deux temps en ce qui concerne l'expression des vérités générales, mais on est dans l'erreur ; il suffit d'amputer les  deux phrases ci-dessus.

- La neuropédagogie **est** une discipline nouvelle. (*On reconnait l'aspect comme celui de la vérité générale.*)
- La neuropédagogie **était** une discipline nouvelle. (*L'aspect de la vérité générale sans restriction **n'est pas** l'aspect valide ; il s'agit maintenant soit de l'aspect courant (procès dans le passé) ou de l'aspect « vérité générale **dans le passé** ».*)

Ceci montre que l'imparfait dans « 1/ » n'aurait pas le même aspect que le présent (l'équivalence n'est vérifiée que dans les conjonctives).

Passons à la question supplémentaire.

============================================================
Comment expliquer qu'on dirait clairement:
**a** Partir est ce qu'elle fit ce jour-là         (alors qu'on aurait tendance à dire:)
**b** Son action ce jour-là fut de partir                                  (?)
Et il y plus troublant encore, j'aurais tendance à dire
**c** « Ce qu'elle fit ce jour-là fut de partir. »
alors qu'on a juste inversé le sujet et l'attribut.

=============================================================

A priori, il n'existe pas de principe interdisant l'une ou l'autre des deux formulations « **a** » et « **b** ». La proposition nominale dans « **a** », « ce qu'elle fit ce jour-là » se réduit à un groupe nominal, dont il faut trouver une formulation correcte; c'est du plus simple : on remplace cette proposition par « son action ce jour-là », et il semble que l'on ne change rien aux termes agencés. Donc, on trouve l'équivalent de « **a** » « Partir est son action ce jour-là » ; cela est équivalent à « Son action ce jour-là est (de) partir ». On voit donc que  l'on a deux formulations qui ne diffèrent que par le temps du verbe, si l'on omet les questions de style, d'idiomaticité.

- Partir est/fut son action ce jour-là.

Le phénomène « troublant » n'est pas un problème ; dans  « Ce qu'elle fit ce jour-là fut de partir. », la partie « Ce qu'elle fit ce jour-là » est une proposition nominale, c'est à dire une unité équivalente à un groupe nominal ; on voit que « partir » est un terme plus spécifique pour « son action », mais qui réfère toujours à la même chose ; donc on a « Son action ce jour-là fut de partir. », et donc « **c** » revient à « **b** ».

Il ne reste plus qu'à s'interroger sur la validité des temps. D'après « 1/ » le présent de vérité générale est parfaitement valide (si le raisonnement ne comporte pas de vice) ; le choix de ce présent n'est qu'une question de point de vue que l'auteur détermine dans l'hypothèse que d'autres temps (à part l'imparfait) donneraient un sens à la phrase. Selon la même partie de l'explication ci-dessus, l'imparfait ne convient pas. Il reste à considérer le passé simple (qui serait selon les impressions de user Benoit, le temps le plus indiqué).

Il n'y a pas de problème, il me semble ; le passé simple permet d'énoncer une vérité dont on ne considère la validité qu'à un certain moment dans le passé.

*exemples*

- Le poisson de cette rivière est mauvais. (*vérité générale*)
- Le poisson de cette rivière fut bon en mai, quand Marthe le préparait. (*simple vérité valide à un certain moment*)

Comment: Merci beaucoup  pour la réponse et la réflexion. Certains cas me paraissent encore difficiles à interpréter. Comment expliquer qu'on dirait clairement: **Partir est ce qu'elle fit ce jour la**, alors qu'on aurait tendance à dire: **Son action ce jour la fut de partir**? Et il y plus troublant encore, j'aurais tendance à dire **Ce qu'elle fit ce jour la fut de partir** alors qu'on a juste inversé le sujet et l'attribut.

Comment: @Benoit Je ne peux pas, de but en blanc, apporter quelque chose de nouveau, et comme vous, je vais devoir me pencher sur cette question de nouveau ; si quelque chose que je penserais intéressant sort des possibilités supplémentaires que vous mentionnez je vous le signalerai aussitôt, mais ne vous attendez pas à un miracle.